# List all pages and children in separate ul

Tags: pages, list

I've been trying to do this all weekend, I'm going round in circles now.

I want to list all pages and their children in separate ul's

The page setup is like this

```
    HOME        ABOUT         CONTACT
                Who we are    Where we are 
                What we do    How to find us
                How we do it
```

I want to output it like this

```
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Who we are</li>
      <li>What we do</li>
      <li>How we do it</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li>Where we are</li>
      <li>How to find us</li>
    </ul>
```

This will give me the top pages in separate ul's

```
    <?php
      $args = array(
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'parent' => 0,
      );
      $pages = get_pages($args);
      foreach($pages as $page){
        ?>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <?php 
                        echo $page->post_title;
                    ?>  
          </li>
        </ul>
        <?php
      }

    ?>
```

I'm now trying to add the child pages to the ul

I'm thinking something like this but this gives me all the pages in each ul

```
    <?php
      $args = array(
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'parent' => 0,
      );
      $pages = get_pages($args);
      foreach($pages as $page){
        ?>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <?php 
                        echo $page->post_title;
                        wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=0&child_of'.$page->ID.'');
                    ?>  
          </li>
        </ul>
        <?php
      }

    ?>
```

Is there a way to say all children of this page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

your code is missing the `=` after `child_of`

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'parent' => 0,
    );
$pages = get_pages($args);
foreach($pages as $page){
    ?>
    <ul>
        <li>
        <?php 
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $page->ID ) . '">' . $page->post_title . '</a>';
        ?>  
        </li>
        <?php  
        wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=0&child_of='.$page->ID.'');
        ?>  
    </ul>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

if you want to make sure to only show one level of child pages, consider to set the `'depth'` parameter to `1`

Comment: Thanks Michael, best part of a day messing with this and I was missing a "="

Comment: Might have spoken too soon. The first echo echo $page->post_title; just gives me text of the page but I need that to be a link as well

Comment: edited to show parent pages as link. this is the edited line: `echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $page->ID ) . '">' . $page->post_title . '</a>';`